# Can't find struct's some field with pragma pack, 64 bits integer

Tags: go, enums, cgo

```
package main

/*
#include <inttypes.h> 
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct _sss {
uint64_t some; // ok
uint32_t wow; // ok
uint64_t some2; // not found
uint64_t some3; // not found
uint64_t some4; // not found
uint32_t some5; // ok
} Type;
#pragma pack()
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := C.Type{}
    s.some = 10; 
    s.wow = 10; 
    s.some2 = 10; 
    s.some5 = 10;
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

I declared struct named C.Type.

If pragma pack(1) and 64 bits members are used together.

```
╭─dire@dire-81w4 ~/workspace
╰─go run test.go                                                                                                                    2 ↵
# command-line-arguments
./test.go:25:6: s.some2 undefined (type _Ctype_struct__sss has no field or method some2)
```

Compilation is possible by removing pragma pack(1).

Go 1.15 version is being used. Do you know why?

Comment: Could you please 1) reformat the tail part of the question so it becomes readable; 2) clarify what exactly happens with "pragma pack(1)"? Let me clarify the second point: your example uses `__attribute__((packed))` (which is GCC-specific, if memory serves me right) but your text suggests the usage of `#pragma pack(1)` is being discussed, which is missing from the example and is a different beast. Hence the question is hard to comprehend, as stated.

Comment: @kostix In the process of editing, `__attribute__` was entered incorrectly. pack(1) is correct. my post is edited.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me: try one of the following: 1) run `go build -x -work` and notice the name of the directory created to keep intermediate files; `-work` makes `go build` not remove it, so you can go there and inspect the generated file `_cgo_gotypes.go`.2) run `go tool cgo yourfile.go` to get the same set of files in the `_obj` subdirectory (which will be created). Either way, you'll see a single field `_ [24]byte` between the `wow` and `some5` fields (`gc` Go 1.15.3 on Linux/amd64 here). If you will report it, please post a link here, thanks.

Comment: _cgo_gotypes.go: 
`type _Ctype_struct__sss struct {some _Ctype_uint64_t wow _Ctype_uint32_t _ [24]byte some5 _Ctype_uint32_t}` 
some variables are hidden. Is it go 1.15 bug?

Comment: Sorry, but how your remark is different from the last two sentences of my previous comment?

Comment: Any new info? Have you found a matching issue in the tracker of filed a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer about my question.

`If the fields of a C struct are aligned such that they can't be represented by a Go struct, then they cannot be accessed directly from cgo. You will have to write functions in C to read and write those fields.`

I nowdays am too busy to comment. It's late, but it's answered.